# Why can I use divergence theorem here?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ a smooth bounded domain s.t. $\mathbb R^d\backslash \Omega $ is connected, and let $u\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^d\backslash \Omega )$ s.t. $\Delta u=0$ and $u$ decay fast at infinity.

In my course it's written :

$$0=-\int_{\mathbb R^d\backslash \Omega }G(x,y)\Delta udy= \int_{\mathbb R^d\backslash \Omega }\nabla u(y)\cdot \nabla _yG(x,y)dy+\int_{\partial \Omega }\partial _\nu u(y)G(x,y)dy.$$

The last equality come from the divergence theorem, but why can we use it here since $\mathbb R^d\backslash \Omega $ is not compact ? Because divergence theorem wants the compactness of the domain as we can see  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem). If the function $u$ would be compacted supported, I would agree, but in this case, I don't really understand.

---

I recall that $G(x,y)$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace equation, i.e. $$G(x,y)=\begin{cases}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln|x-y|& d\geq 2\\ \frac{1}{d(d-2)|B_1||x-y|^{d-2}}&d\geq 2\end{cases},$$
and $\Delta _x G(x,y)=\Delta _y G(x,y)=\delta_{x=y}.$

Comment: Let $B_R = \{ x \in \mathbb R^d : |x| \leq R \}$ and study the integral over $B_R \setminus \Omega$ (for $R$ big enough). Then let $R \to \infty.$

Comment: @md2perpe: does it really work ? If yes, it should work with every functions not necessarily schwartz...

Comment: As long as $u$ decays fast enough for the integral over the outer boundary $\partial B_R$ to tend to $0$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: @md2perpe: Could you please give me a proof or a reference of it ? Because I don't really understand why. Thank you very much

Comment: Assume that $v$ is a vector field decaying so fast that $\oint_{\partial B_R} v \cdot n \, dS \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$.

Then, since $B_R \setminus \Omega$ is compact, we have
$$
\int_{B_R \setminus \Omega} \nabla \cdot v \, dV
= \oint_{\partial(B_R \setminus \Omega)} v \cdot n \, dS
= \oint_{\partial B_R} v \cdot n \, dS + \oint_{\partial \Omega} v \cdot n \, dS
$$

Taking limits as $R \to \infty$ we get
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d \setminus \Omega} \nabla \cdot v \, dV = \oint_{\partial \Omega} v \cdot n \, dS
$$